# Dumb permission denied issue preventing me from cloning a simple repo

Tags: git, github, ssh

So I’m very embarrassed to be opening this question, but I actually can’t figure it out. I am having issues cloning a GitHub repo (yes, believe it or not…), yet I have followed all the necessary steps and have cloned repos many times before.

So… I have generated a new SSH key, as per githubs documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

And I have added it to GitHub too (and yes, as a SSH key under SSH and GPG keys) - and yes, that was from catting the .pub file and pasting it in correctly.

I can even run `ssh -T git@github.com` and it returns  `You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access`.

So… when I try to clone the repo with the clone command (i.e. `sudo git clone git@github.com:user/repo.git`) via SSH, it asks for this:

```
Warning: the ECDSA host key for 'github.com' differs from the key for the IP address '140.82.121.4'
Offending key for IP in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:2
Matching host key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:3
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

To which I obviously say `yes`. Yet it then returns this error:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists
```

I also tried `ssh-keygen -R github.com` and `ssh-keygen -R IP_ADDRESS` as per other stack overflow threads, but nothing. I then deleted the known hosts file altogether and tried again, but nothing.

Can anyone tell me what’s the dumb thing I’m not doing right here?

Comment: Why are you using `sudo` for git clone?

Comment: If the clone fails without `sudo` due to permission, you could 1) add the user account (printed by `whoami`) to the group of the current directory (the 4th column printed by `ls -alFd .`); 2) change the owner (the 3th column printed by `ls -alFd .`) to the user account; 3) go to another directory where the user account has permission to read and write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ssh -T git@github.com` and `sudo git clone git@github.com:user/repo` use different keys, because the first one is done as your regular user and the second is done as root.

Remove `sudo` from the clone command, and both the clone and any future network operations on that repo (fetches, pulls, pushes, etc.) should work fine.

Comment: Thanks. Sudo did make a difference but another error occurred after but I change the ownership of the folder and then ran without sudo and it worked